# rails routing to session_index instead of session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here is code from my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :session, only: [:create, :destroy, :new] 
end
```

and the relevant output of `rake routes` is

```
session_index POST   /session(.:format)      session#create
new_session   GET    /session/new(.:format)  session#new
session       DELETE /session/:id(.:format)  session#destroy
```

My question is, why does `session#create` route to `session_index`, and not simply `session`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy, :new]
```

As per Rails convention, if you use `singular` resource, then simply use `resource`and for `plural` resource, you should use `resources`.

[Resource Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)